# 'Correct the classpath of your application' in a Springboot Configuration in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have such an application with an IntelliJ-Idea IDE that has a Springboot configuration that errors out and gives the following recommendation:

```
The following method did not exist:

org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext.setApplicationStartup(Lorg/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup;)V

The method's class, org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/C:/Users/tlmitch/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.class

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
```

I'm relatively new to IntelliJ-Idea and Springboot.  If this were say Eclipse - I would probably just go to the Java Build Path and add the jar file that contains the class.

I'm less familiar with IntelliJ.  So far if something is missing, I've just been running 'npm install' and that usually takes care of it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks much

Comment: Your error mentions .m2 - that suggests Maven to me.  If your pom.xml calls for the spring-boot-starter-parent it'll bring the Spring JAR into the project.  If you are not using Maven, you should.  If you cannot you should add the JAR to a /lib file and add all those JARs to the CLASSPATH in your project configuration.  Stick with IntelliJ - it's worlds better than Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate it.  And yes I am using Maven.  There isn't any sort of a parent tag in the pom.xml file.  Regarding correcting the classpath - I can see where the spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE library is listed in the dependencies.  I'm just not sure how to correct the issue.

Comment: Find the parent and use it. You should be using Soring Boot, not raw Soring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error suggests:

```
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
```

you need to make sure your classpath contains only one such class. You can use Navigate | Class action to see if there are multiple versions of this class exists in project and exclude the duplicated library dependency in Maven `pom.xml` file.

Comment: I'm a bit inexperienced with pom.xml files; I'm having trouble mapping the multiple versions of the class to the content of the pom.xml file.  If I do a cntrl-shift-n and then look for instances of the ConfigurableApplicationContext class - it returns with 8 individual instances.  
For example, it indicates ConfigurableApplicationContext is in a 5.2.8.RELEASE and a 5.2.10.RELEASE of the package org.springframework.context.  I believe I understand <exclusions> in the pom file - but I can't find any instances org.springframework.context in the pom.xml file to exclude one of the releases from.

Answer (score 6):

If you've added Spring dependencies in your **pom.xml** file, they might be conflicting with the Spring dependencies in the **lib** folder in your project directory. Deleting the **lib** folder will fix this. (just make sure your project does not depend on other libraries in the **lib** folder before deleting).

Comment: Saved the day!!